# JSF2.0 Composite Component not getting rendered in MYFaces

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component, websphere-8

I developed a sample project to test composite components in JSF2.0.

Here is my sample code

My test file

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
  xmlns:tp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/test"
  >
<h:body>
    <h:form>
    <h:outputLabel value="Success"/>
       <tp:loginComponent 
          usernameLabel="Enter User Name: " 
          usernameValue="#{login.name}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
>
    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="usernameLabel" />
        <composite:attribute name="usernameValue" />
    </composite:interface>
    <composite:implementation>
        <h:form>
            #{cc.attrs.usernameLabel} : 
            <h:inputText id="username" value="#{cc.attrs.usernameValue}" />
        </h:form>
    </composite:implementation>
```

> When I deploy it on Websphere 8.5 the composite component is not getting rendered.Please help me identify the issue

Thanks

Comment: Both files you posted here are missing there closing </html> tag. Also is the path and filename of your composite: resources/test/loginComponent.xhtml

Comment: @Eelke : I have the </html> in my code.It was not copied here by mistake.My composite component name is success.xhtml and I have placed it in WebContent/test folder

Answer (score 2):

You have to adjust the location and name of the file. Otherwise JSF won't find it.

The line

```
xmlns:tp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/test"
```

Points JSF to the folder `resources/test` (relative to the root of your web pages). Assuming WebContent is the root for your webpages the resources folder should be inside that.

When JSF sees `<tp:loginComponent .... />` it is going to look in the folder for a file called `loginComponent.xhtml`.

**EDIT**

Because there can be many kinds of resources in your resources folder it is best to create a subfolder for components. I usually call it comps. So that would give you the path
`/WebContent/resources/comps` place in this folder a file named `loginComponent.xhtml` with your component.

Change the namespace line to: `xmlns:tp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/comps"` (that comps is in resources is implied but not specified in the URL).

See also the [java ee tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html).

Comment: I have now chnaged the line to xmlns:tp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/resources                and renamed the file to loginComponent.xhtml and it is still not working any inputs please.resources is  a folder in my web root